# Some bug with char* and new

Tags: c++, object, pointers, memory

I have same code:

.hpp file:

```
class CConsoleModel
{
char* ParametersBuffer;

...

public:
CConsoleModel() ;  // - basic constructor;
~CConsoleModel() ; // -basic destructor
char *DeterminationParameter(std::string _command, int _parametersize);
...
};
```

.cpp file:

```
char *CConsoleModel::DeterminationParameter(std::string _command, int _parametersize)
{
  ParametersBuffer = new char[_parametersize];
  unsigned int HexValue;
 _command = _command.substr(_command.length() - (_parametersize*2),(_parametersize*2));
  //do conversion of the string to the required dimension (_parametrsize):
  for (int i(0); i<_parametersize;i++)
  {
    std::stringstream CommandSteam;
    CommandSteam<< std::hex <<_command[2*i];
    CommandSteam<< std::hex <<_command[2*i +1];
    CommandSteam >> std::hex >> HexValue;
    ParametersBuffer[i] = static_cast<char> (HexValue);
  }
  return  ParametersBuffer;
}
```

Program build, but crash when run.

If I change `ParametersBuffer = new char[_parametersize]`

to `char* ParametersBuffer = new char[_parametersize]`

everything works.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I suspect that the problem is in the `...`s. Post the smallest code example you can come up with that compiles and runs and shows the problem.

Comment: There's not enough code to be sure, but you're probably forgetting the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722), copying the `CConsoleModel`, and deleting the same buffer twice. Why not use `std::string` or `std::vector<char>` rather than messing around with `new`?

Comment: My guess is that you delete the ParametersBuffer multiple times, or use it after deletion. Do you delete ParametersBuffer in the destructor (`~CConsoleModel`)?

Comment: Yes, I use delete[] ParametersBuffer in ~CConsoleModel

Comment: @user2746837: Have you also implemented or deleted the copy constructor and copy-assignment operator, per the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722)? If not, the class is a crash waiting to happen.

Comment: @BenVoigt: yeah, my mistake - would have seen my mistake much quicker if the code had a scope identifier on the variable (e.g. `m_ParametersBuffer`). Multiple `delete`s seem to be the issue but hard to tell without seeing a bit more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We strongly recommend to use `std::vector` instead of manual memory allocation.

```
class CConsoleModel
{
    std::vector<char> ParametersBuffer;
```

and

```
ParametersBuffer.resize(_parametersize);
```

...

```
return &ParametersBuffer[0];
```

BTW

```
std::stringstream CommandSteam;
    CommandSteam<< std::hex <<_command[2*i];
    CommandSteam<< std::hex <<_command[2*i +1];
    CommandSteam >> std::hex >> HexValue;
```

is horrible and won't work when you have single digit values.  Try

```
HexValue = (_command[2*i] << 8) | _command[2*i+1];
```

Answer (score 0):

My psychic debugging skills tell me that you're missing either the copy constructor or copy assignment operator (or that your destructor doesn't properly clean up the buffer).

If you just use `std::string`  your problems with this will be solved.